# Authenticate to confluence before launching a url

Tags: confluence

I need to launch a Confluence page from another website. The Confluence page is access protected and I need to do the authentication before the page is launched so that Confluence doesn't ask for a username/password.

Is there a way to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for application links. There is a [good post](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Confluence-questions/How-do-I-set-up-application-links-where-address-of-3rd-party/qaq-p/296571) on Atlassian about how to preform authentication from one app to another by passing the authenticated headers upon request.